# Python 3.2: Run python programs and create user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.2

Ok, so what i am trying to do is i have a bunch of python programs that are just tests (using the unittest library). I would like to create a python program that runs each python program back to back and gives me kind of a report at the end (would be the best situation) or just stops running if one fails.

The hard part about this is each program requires a user input (a simple Y for yes). How can I run each python program (i have run across the `executefile("script.py")` command but have not tested it out), then insert the input from the user (a simple Y), and either have it stop when a test fails (easier) or preferably be able to tell which ones fail and print the results of what failed and what passed after they all run.

I am still learning python (self-taught) so sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use the `unittest` module to run all your tests?

```
% python -m unittest -h
Usage: python -m unittest [options] [tests]

Options:
  -h, --help       Show this message
  -v, --verbose    Verbose output
  -q, --quiet      Minimal output
  -f, --failfast   Stop on first failure
  -c, --catch      Catch control-C and display results
  -b, --buffer     Buffer stdout and stderr during test runs

Examples:
  python -m unittest test_module               - run tests from test_module
  python -m unittest module.TestClass          - run tests from module.TestClass
  python -m unittest module.Class.test_method  - run specified test method

[tests] can be a list of any number of test modules, classes and test
methods.

Alternative Usage: python -m unittest discover [options]

Options:
  -v, --verbose    Verbose output
  -f, --failfast   Stop on first failure
  -c, --catch      Catch control-C and display results
  -b, --buffer     Buffer stdout and stderr during test runs
  -s directory     Directory to start discovery ('.' default)
  -p pattern       Pattern to match test files ('test*.py' default)
  -t directory     Top level directory of project (default to
                   start directory)

For test discovery all test modules must be importable from the top
level directory of the project.
```

#### Documentation:

- http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface
- http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/unittest.html#test-discovery
- http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/unittest.html#unittest.TextTestRunner

Comment: This would work great except for the user input part of each test. I am really looking for a way so that i dont have to go through each test (there are quite a few of them) and get rid of that part. I would prefer to be able to run the command and go do something else, instead of having to sit there and insert y for each test

Comment: If you want to answer *yes* to all the scripts, you could try with the [yes(1)](http://man.cx/yes) utility: `yes | python -m unittest [options]` or `yes Y | python -m unittest [options]` ...

Answer (score 0):

You could test the functions inside your script and bypass the "raw_input" part which require human intervention. Exemple :

hello.py:

```
def main():
    print "hello world"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = True
    while test:
       test = raw_input() != 'Y'
    main()
```

test_hello.py:

```
import hello

if __name__ == "__main__":
    hello.main()
```

For testing python code, you can consider [Nose](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose/1.1.2) as an unittest replacement.